# Restrict user to stop a windows service

Tags: c, windows, winapi, service

I'm involved in writing a Windows Service. Before I start writing it, I'd like to know

1. What are the points to be considered in terms of LOGIN USERS, specifically how to restrict other users from "stopping a service"?
2. What are the generic points should I consider while writing a service?
3. How can I display a warning alert once the user tries to stop the service?

Note: I am trying to write the service in C.

Thanks.

Comment: Details about USERS : I want to know the privileges for both the users ( Normal users and Administrators ). It is concluded that Normal users cant stop a service. I'd like to know more on how to display a warning window once the administrator tries to stop the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Normal users wont be able to stop services. It requires administration privileges.
2. You can't do anything that involves writing to the screen or reading the keyboard/mouse.
3. You will need to write an application that sits in the background (hidden window) and  communicates with the service via some interprocess communication method (RPC/sockets etc).  **This** application will receive a message from the service that displays a message box or otherwise communicates with the user.

I would try to write the code (for both service & application) in C# as most of the hard work (registering with SCM, start/stop etc) has been done for you.

Comment: +1 for the details. OP really needs to post more info on the so-called users.

Comment: For #3, a service can call `MessageBox()` with the `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION` flag, or `WTSSendMessage()`, to display a simple popup message dialog directly without needing to use a separate application to handle it on the service's behalf.  But if you want to customize the dialog, or display any other kind of UI, then yes, a separate app is needed.

Comment: Details about USERS : I want to know the privileges for both the users ( Normal users and Administrators ). It is concluded that Normal users cant stop a service. I'd like to know more on how to display a warning window once the administrator tries to stop the service.

Comment: When the service is shutting down, it can communicate that to the application that is monitoring the service, which can display a message to the user.