# Warning window once the user tries to stop a service

Tags: c, windows, winapi, service, windows-services

I'm writing a service in "C" and I'd like to display a warning window once the user tries to stop the service ( With "OK" and "Cancel" Buttons ).

Is there any specific windows API available to achieve this?
Any other simple ways are there to achieve??

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question, [Restrict user to stop a windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551377/restrict-user-to-stop-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Windows services are unable to interact directly with the user's desktop, so they will be unable to show a user interface of any kind.

This shouldn't really be a big deal, though. You have to have adequate permissions to stop and start a service, and by default, only Administrators have those rights. If you don't want users inadvertently stopping your service, then you should take advantage of permissions to solve that problem for you.

Comment: If serviceStatus is set to "SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP" cant we display a UI??

Comment: No. Services cannot display a UI. You can write an event to the Event Log, but this seems rather pointless.

Comment: Could you suggest some links for detailed explanation on services??

Comment: I've answered a handful of questions about Windows Services here on Stack Overflow, most of them explaining how/why services cannot display a UI. You can find the list of them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A366904+%5Bwindows-service%5D). I'm sure Google has some interesting references, too.

Answer (score 0):

You stop a service with Service control panel; your service normally doesn't have access to this control panel process, so you can't override it's UI and present a dialog asking OK/Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned the hard way that any calls made to the UI from a service will cause it to hang. MSDN does have a page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502%28VS.85%29.aspx) on work arounds.

Comment: Do note the caveat in bold at the very top of the article: *"**Important** Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista. Therefore, the techniques mentioned in the section titled Using an Interactive Service should not be used in new code."*

Comment: There's still the WTSSendMessage function for showing a dialog box. It sounds like if he needs anything more advanced he'd need to write a hidden GUI app, which the article also talks about.

Comment: Problem is, you can't guarantee that there's always going to be a user logged in to receive that message. And yes, you could create a GUI application that runs in a specific user context, communicating with the service through an IPC mechanism, but again, there's no guarantee that the user hasn't forcibly terminated that application before trying to stop the service. Either of those, and plenty of other scenarios, will hang your machine, which is probably not what he wanted. These are stop-gap workarounds, intended to debug or muddle through an already broken app, not to write a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want anybody to be able to stop the service, just tell the service manager that you don't accept stop messages.  You could instead provide an application that stops the service (using some form of IPC) and that application could present as many warning messages as you wanted.

On the other hand, this *will* annoy your users, and it is unlikely to be necessary.  By default, only administrators can stop services, and people are unlikely to try to stop your service without a good reason.