# Windows service message in system tray

Tags: c, windows, winapi, service, windows-services

I've posted a similar similar query  [Link to my previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561081/warning-window-once-the-user-tries-to-stop-a-service)

Still I need some more clarifications on this topic,

1) Can I display a warning message using "WTSSendMessage", once the user tries to stop the windows service?? ( In all versions of windows ( XP, VISTA, 7 ) ).

2) If the above method is not possible, **"Can I display a warning message in sysyem tray of my computer"**

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I display a warning message using `WTSSendMessage`, once the user tries to stop the windows service?

Yes you can. The MSDN document [Service Changes for Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb203962.aspx) says this (emphasis mine):

> Services have always run in session 0. Before Windows Vista, the first user to log on was also assigned to session 0. Now, session 0 is reserved exclusively for services and other applications not associated with an interactive user session. (The first user to log on is connected to session 1, the second user to log on is connected to session 2, and so on.) Session 0 does not support processes that interact with the user.
>   This change means that a service cannot post or send a message to an application and an application cannot send or post a message to a service. In addition, services cannot display a user interface item such as a dialog box directly. **A service can use the WTSSendMessage function to display a dialog box in another session**.

Comment: Do I need to create a seperate application for this?? and use WTSSendmessage in that application??

Comment: I created my own service and when i try to stop that I need this warning message. here "hserverhandle" is service handle or something different??

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg465093 And read the documentation of `WTSSendMessage`. It tells you what all the parameters are. Don't start guessing.